# Keys.Numpad0 comes in as Keys.System when ALT is pressed

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to detect hotkeys of ALT+1 through ALT+9 but when ALT is pressed the key comes in as Key.System.  When CTRL+NumPad0 is pressed it key is Key.NumPad0 which is correct.

```
private void MainWindow_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    bool isAlt = Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftAlt) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightAlt);
    bool isCtrl = Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightCtrl);

    string ctrlMod = string.Empty;

    if (isAlt)
    {
        ctrlMod = "alt + " + e.Key.ToString();
    }

    if (isCtrl)
    {
        ctrlMod = "ctrl + " + e.Key.ToString();
    }

    Debug.WriteLine("Key is " + ctrlMod);
}
```

ALT+NumPad0 through ALT+NumPad9 produces:

> Key is alt + System

Ctrl works properly

Key is ctrl + NumPad1
Key is ctrl + NumPad2
Key is ctrl + NumPad3

Comment: It might have something to do with Windows Alt Codes

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4355ab9a-9214-4fe1-87ea-b32dfc22946c/issue-with-alt-key-and-key-down-event?forum=wpf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `Keyboard.Modifiers` and `KeyEventArgs.SystemKey` properties to detect `ALT+1` through `ALT+9`:

```
private void MainWindow_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Alt)
    {
        string ctrlMod = "alt + " + e.SystemKey.ToString();
        Debug.WriteLine("Key is " + ctrlMod);
    }
}
```

---

```
private void MainWindow_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    bool isAlt = Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Alt;
    bool isCtrl = Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control;

    string ctrlMod = string.Empty;

    if (isAlt)
    {
        ctrlMod = "alt + " + e.SystemKey.ToString();
    }

    if (isCtrl)
    {
        ctrlMod = "ctrl + " + e.Key.ToString();
    }

    Debug.WriteLine("Key is " + ctrlMod);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think maccettura is right and its to do with 'Windows Alt Codes'.  I can get around it using

```
if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.NumPad0)) { }
```